# HttpsUrlConnection with SSLSocketFactory class takes too long to connect in Android

Tags: android, ssl, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

I want to use TLS protocol with `HttpsUrlConnection` in Android. For this, I am overriding `SSLSocketFactory` class and setting TLS protocol using `setEnabledProtocol()` method. Then I am setting the `SSLSocketFactory` in `HttpsUrlConnection` using `connection.setSSLSocketFactory()` method.

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
SSLSocketFactoryEx socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactoryEx();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
conn.connect();
```

Here SSLSocketFactoryEx is my custom class inheriting from SSLSocketFactory class.
Inside `SSLSocketFactoryEx` class, I am setting `setEnabledProtocol()` method with TLS protocol.

Now the problem is when I use `SSLSocketFactory` class, the `HttpsUrlConnection` takes more than a sec to connect. As per the below link, there is a bug related to reverse DNS in Android due to which it takes time. I followed the approach described there to fix the issue but still it is slow.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13117

Is there a way I can improve the performance?

Comment: `Is there a way I can improve the performance?` prolly yes, you need to modify your code ...

Comment: I have described my question in detail. What can I do to improve the performance?

Comment: check what takes more time `connect()` or `new SSLSocketFactoryEx()` ... there is no need for new socket factory for every openConnection/connect pair

Comment: SSLSocketFactoryEx is not taking any time. connect() is taking time. If I remove setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory), everything is fine.

Comment: Is there a way I can set the SSLSocketFactory once and use it for all connections? Will setDefaultSSLSocketFactory() work?

Comment: yes(you could also use singleton implementation and use something like `conn.setSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactoryEx.getInstance());`) but it will not help if you are doing to much stuff in `createSocket` of your `SSLSocketFactory` implementation ... **again, use profiler** and check where is the bottleneck ... it is hard to guess